# Clarification of lifetime beta sites like this

Tags: discussion

[Graduation, site closure, and a clearer outlook on the health of SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites?cb=1)

Looks like we should be in the clear. We stay pretty active and we keep the board clean. Yay us!

Answer (score 2):

We're like the biggest beta site or the smallest graduated site. I think this place could use a bit more life, but I'm pretty happy with the amount of people I've seen coming back saying something to the effect of:

> I got some great info on this site, and have made good progress, and
>   know I want to know x/y/z

I keep the Q&A's I like on my favorites and do a lot of copying or url's.

Comment: This is true. Unfortunately, unless we can start getting more interest in the theory rather than the strict practice, we aren't likely (at this point) to really start driving a lot more traffic and visits per day. That's the key metric that will keep us from graduating.